# Flask returns 404 with manager

Tags: python, flask, flask-script

I have a small rest application with the following structure

```
Basedir
  - manage.py
  - load_gen
    - __init__.py
    - app.py
    - models.py
```

code snippet from manage.py

```
from load_gen import app, db
from load_gen.models import User
from flask.ext.script import Manager

manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

code snippet from **init**.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from load_gen import models
from load_gen import app
```

and finally app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort,make_response,url_for    
from models import User

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
        'done': False
    }
]
def make_public_task(task):
    new_task = {}
    for field in task:
        if field == 'id':
            new_task['uri'] = url_for('get_task', task_id=task['id'], _external=True)
        else:
            new_task[field] = task[field]
    return new_task

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': [make_public_task(task) for task in tasks]})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try to run this with python manage.py runserver, my app route is not registered and I keep getting 404 Not Found. 
url used - localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks.

I have spent last 3 hours trying to figure out but am stuck. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `app` in `manage.py` is your app, but the module instead (due to the last couple of lines in `__init__.py`).  That could be the issue, though I'm surprised you're not running into other issues.

Comment: you have app = Flask("app") in init.py (__init__.py ?) and app = Flask(__name__) in app.py. it's strange also

Comment: app in manage.py prints "<Flask 'load_gen'>". Its loaded from __init_.py. Can you tell me what else I need to use there?

Comment: @Gerard Rozsavolgyi - I was testing it. I changed it Flask(__name__). Will edit the code.

Comment: You have three things named `app`. First you create an `Application` instance in `__init__.py`. Then you import a module named `app`, shadowing the instance. Your third `app` is the instance inside `app.py`. The two instances are going to going to give you problems, especially when the first gets shadowed by a module.

Comment: @dirn - I changed app.py to load_app.py. Still nothing. I tried this helper [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/117/) and got following results `static                                             HEAD,OPTIONS,GET     /static/[filename]`. I believe my manager is not somehow registering my flask app.

Answer (score 1):

The `app` you run and the `app` with which you register your routes are not the same.

In `manage.py` you have

```
from load_gen import app

manager = Manager(app)
```

In `app.py` (now `load_app.py`) you have

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': [make_public_task(task) for task in tasks]})
```

You need to use the same `app` everywhere. Don't define `app` in `load_app.py` and you should be all set, just remove the import at the end of `__init__.py` and change `load_app.py` to have

```
from load_gen import app
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much! Spent way too long on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `manage.py` is setting up things in a strange way. I would put some of that code at the end of `__init__.py`. After you import your models and the views (in app.py), create your manager, at the bottom of init.py:

```
manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

And then in your manage.py, all you have to do is this:

```
from load_gen import manager
manager.run()
```

Because the manager object is created inside the application module, and therefore has the views and database created in the proper context.